# TextBox Binding doesn't work when switching Tab in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a TextBox in a TabControl. If I edit the text in the box and then switch to another tab, the text is lost. If I change focus (via TAB key on keyboard) and then switch to another tab, the new text is set in my viewmodel.

Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="TabSwitchProblem.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding PageContent}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<PageViewModel> Pages
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<PageViewModel>)GetValue(PagesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PagesProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PagesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Pages", typeof(ObservableCollection<PageViewModel>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Pages = new ObservableCollection<PageViewModel>();
        Pages.Add(new PageViewModel());
        Pages.Add(new PageViewModel());
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
public class PageViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public string PageContent
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PageContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PageContentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PageContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PageContent", typeof(string), typeof(PageViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

How can I be sure to get the text updated in my viewmodel?

Comment: Catch the tab index changed and notify your models property?

Comment: I know, how to catch the SelectionChanged Event. But what do you mean by notifying my model? How could I get the value in the TextBox and set it in my model?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` to the `<TextBox Text="{Binding PageContent}" />` line.

Code should look like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PageContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

That should work.

Comment: Oops sorry it should have been PropertyChanged not LostFocus. I copied the code from something I had done.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` if you want your binding to update the target every time the value changes. By default the `UpdateSourceTrigger` for `Text` property of a `TextBox` is `LostFocus`, which updates the target only after the focus is lost.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PageContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: This works. But it has the side effect that it triggers with every key stroke.

Comment: That's the expected behavior of `PropertyChanged`, not a side effect.

Comment: I understand this, but I was searching for a way to update my property when the user clicks on another tab. I don't want to update with every key stroke. So for my problem this is a workaround with a side effect. But in this special case it's a side effect that I can accept.

Comment: I agree @MTR. I just added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59842886/634805) that explains how to force the update without changing the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The previously accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33547053/634805), although it works, involves changing the binding behavior of the textbox to `UpdatesourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. This may not be acceptable for some usages of textbox or other input-accepting controls.

A simple fix for this is to manually set focus to another element on your control (or the tabcontrol itself) in code-behind on `SelectionChanged` of your TabControl. That way the currently focused input element actually loses focus, triggering the binding:

```
<TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl" SelectionChanged="MyTabControl_OnSelectionChanged">
```

```cs
private void MyTabControl_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTabControl.Focus();
}
```